# Looking to write Bluetooth 'hcitool' equivelant in Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluez

I have used Bluez Bluetooth stack in Linux which comes with a handy utility 'hcitool'. Looking to build something like that in Windows with same or equivalent functionality. Specifically, 'hcitool name < MAC >', which shows if the specified device is within range.
Any guidance will be appreciated.

I have Windows SDK v7 with Visual Studio 2010, using C/C++

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my [32feet.NET](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet) library something like the following.

**EDIT 3rd March:** I've now added code to *directly* lookup the device by address rather than by using device discovery; so that's a simple 'new BluetoothDeviceInfo(...)'.

See if that finds the device you want. This requires the remote device to only be in "Connectable" mode whereas the former requires it to be in "Discoverable" mode. (BTW I've left the discovery code in place.)

**EDIT 8th March:** Now does a connect (using the SDP API) to check that the device is in range (and in connectable mode).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace hcitool
{
    partial class Program
    {
        static bool infoRatherThanName;
        static BluetoothAddress _searchAddress;

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Please specify command.");
                return 2;
            }
            var cmd = args[0];
            switch (cmd) {
                case "name":
                    infoRatherThanName = false;
                    break;
                case "info":
                    infoRatherThanName = true;
                    break;
                //-
                case "dev":
                    return ShowRadios();
                //case "auth":
                //    return CauseAuth(GETADDRESS());
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Command: '" + cmd + "'");
            }
            if (args.Length < 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("Please specify device address.");
                return 2;
            }
            var addrS = args[1];
            _searchAddress = BluetoothAddress.Parse(addrS);
            //
            var dev = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(_searchAddress);
            bool isInRange = GetCanConnectTo(dev);
            if (isInRange) {
                PrintDevice(dev);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't see that device.");
            }
            //
            Console.WriteLine("simple");
            return Simple();
            //return Fancier();
        }

        //----
        private static int ShowRadios()
        {
            BluetoothRadio[] list;
            try {
                list = BluetoothRadio.AllRadios;
            } catch (Exception) {
                return 1;
            }
            Debug.Assert(list.Length != 0, "Expect zero radios case to raise an error.");
            foreach (var curR in list) {
                Console.WriteLine("* {0} '{1}'", curR.LocalAddress, curR.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", curR.SoftwareManufacturer);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", curR.Manufacturer);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", curR.Mode);
            }//for
            return 0;
        }

        private static int CauseAuth(BluetoothAddress addr)
        {
            BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(addr, null);
            return 0;
        }

        //----
        static int Simple()
        {
            BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices;
            BluetoothDeviceInfo foundDev = null;
            var cli = new BluetoothClient();
            // Fast: Remembered/Authenticated
            devices = cli.DiscoverDevices(255, true, true, false, false);
            SimpleCheckDevice(devices, ref foundDev);
            if (foundDev == null) {
                // Slow: Inquiry
                cli.DiscoverDevices(255, false, false, true, false);
                SimpleCheckDevice(devices, ref foundDev);
            }
            //
            if (foundDev != null) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        private static void SimpleCheckDevice(IEnumerable<BluetoothDeviceInfo> devices,
            ref BluetoothDeviceInfo foundDev)
        {
            foreach (var cur in devices) {
                if (cur.DeviceAddress == _searchAddress) {
                    foundDev = cur;
                    PrintDevice(cur);
                }
            }//for
        }

        private static void PrintDevice(BluetoothDeviceInfo cur)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("* Found device: '{0}' ", cur.DeviceName);
            if (infoRatherThanName) {
                try {
                    var vs = cur.GetVersions();
                    Console.WriteLine(vs.Manufacturer);
                    Console.WriteLine(vs.LmpVersion);
                    Console.WriteLine(vs.LmpSubversion);
                    Console.WriteLine(vs.LmpSupportedFeatures);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to get remote device versions info: "
                        + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        //----
        private static bool GetCanConnectTo(BluetoothDeviceInfo device)
        {
            bool inRange;
            Guid fakeUuid = new Guid("{F13F471D-47CB-41d6-9609-BAD0690BF891}");
            try {
                ServiceRecord[] records = device.GetServiceRecords(fakeUuid);
                Debug.Assert(records.Length == 0, "Why are we getting any records?? len: " + records.Length);
                inRange = true;
            } catch (SocketException) {
                inRange = false;
            }
            return inRange;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try. I did download this library earlier, but being clueless on c#, I couldn't make any progress.

Comment: I managed to build and run this application (by modifying 'Chat2Desk' sample). However it only returns paired device. (Similar results with Windows BT SDK). Unlike the Linux 'hcitool', which can query un-paired devices too. My research shows that I need to query low level driver layer, at radio level. But I maybe wrong. Any further advice? (Thanks again for the quick app though!).

Comment: Unable to compile this one:
`error CS0117: 'InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothRadio' does not contain a definition for 'GetAllRadios`

`error CS1061: 'InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothRadio' does not contain a definition for 'Modes' and no extension method 'Modes'`

Comment: Ok. Managed to build this too (after some tweaking). It does display name of one device (my ipod), without being paired. HOWEVER it continues to do so even if I disable the BT on ipod. So it is reading from some cache because the ipod was previously discovered by the PC. For a totally new device, the results are same as if device is not found (ie no name printed).

The Linux tool on the other hand displays output only if the device has BT turned on and is within range. Does not need to be in discoverable mode.
ShowRadios() prints correct info on local radio though. Simple() seem to do nothing.

Comment: Ahh ok. I should have asked at the beginning how hcitool behaved. :-,)  So hcitool -- as per its name -- is apparently using Bluetooth HCI commands, in this case apparently CreateConnection and RemoteNameRequest. Most stacks hide the user from the name lookup process and do it automatically. So I think we'll have to cheat a little, see the updated code which check in range by trying connection (using the SDP API). I've also removed the references to the new library version functions.

Comment: OK. This one works. Detects the presence of the device (new or previously known) correctly. However, prints name of only the previously known device, but that is minor. I will call it an answer!
Thanks again for the persistance!

Comment: Phew got there. :-)  There's no way in most of the Bluetooth stacks I've worked with to force a re-read of the remote device's name. We've not really found a way to force the MSFT stack to re-read the name.

Comment: We could re-read the name for 'detected' case using one the previous methods in the 2nd last revision of your code (I wished I started versioning it from start). But that again is not necessary anyway.

On the side note, I have started implementing this in C++ as a CLR project to fulfill my objectives. Having no knowledge of C# or .NET I am facing beginner's issues, mostly about types. I will post the final results (if successful).
Thanks again!